# Mobile Game - Do I need visual feedback?

Tags: user-experience, visualization

I am currently on a game for windows phone 8.1 where the user can use items. If the user tries to use a item which he doesn't own a sound gets played. If now a user plays without sound or listens to music it might be that he doesn't realize that he tries to use it without realizing why it won't work.

Should I make a visual feedback?

Comment: Yes, you should. You should never rely solely on audio for feedback.

Comment: as a side benefit, you will also make hearing impaired people able to play your game, which is nice by itself...

Comment: Better yet, provide a visual indication *before* they to try to use the item, e.g. change its icon to grayscale if it's not available for use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You already answered your own question:

> If now a user plays without sound or listens to music it might be that
>   he doesn't realize that he tries to use it without realizing why it
>   won't work.

That's the most important reason.

Games feel better when audio and visual feedback are combined.

Comment: Even more on mobile games, where people most play games with no sounds. This is important too with desktop games since the player maybe hearing his fav music while playing the game

Comment: And what would be the best way to do so ?
It's a pretty small field so when the user presses the image he probably won't see the image. But I also don't want to cover the whole game screen.

Comment: You could splash a red X over the item button in conjunction with a buzzer sound.

Comment: @Lexu - You could simply do a short camera shake effect.  That should get the user's attention that he did something wrong.  Or a short duration transparent(ish) red screen overlay.